# How can a WCF talk to Web Application and Sharepoint Web Services at the same time?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, sharepoint, authentication

**Web Application - > WCF Service - > Sharepoint User Profile Web Service**

I have a web application, a WCF service and Sharepoint 2010 Web Service.

Sharepoint 2010 uses security mode = "TransportCredential only" for authentication by default, and the web application uses "Windows" as security mode.

and sharepoint 2010 service uses Ntlm as client credential type, while web application uses 
"Windows" as client credential type.

How can i configure WCF service to be able to communicate with both Sharepoint Service and Web application at the same time.

**Web Application**

```
<security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
          </security>
```

**WCF Service**

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
       realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
     </security>
```

Comment: Have you looked at exposing separate endpoints?  One for Sharepoint and one for the Web app?  That would allow you to configure security for each endpoint individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tim helped me get the answer**

Have you looked at exposing separate endpoints? One for Sharepoint and one for the Web app? That would allow you to configure security for each endpoint individually. **-Tim**